# Minimal condition(s) for the emission of a photon to occur

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, education

I was working out a practice problem where you needed to give all the possible states (where the emission of a photon occurs) of a H-atom at excited 5d state. So I started by whriting down all the possible states [see picture][image: ]]

So my question is, what are the minimal conditions for photon emission to occur?
for example:

- from a higher n quantumnumber to a lower quantumnumber n => This would give 16 possible states
- from a higher l quantumnumber to lower quantumber l => This would give 19 possible states
- other conditions???

Please let me know :)

Thanks in advance

ps: the yellow marked numbers are the possible transitions given by folowing the selection rules.